# Implementing Hit-Highlighting in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

I am working with SharePoint 2013 search. I am using a Customized display template (using Result Type) to display the search results. It all works fine.

I would like to implement Hit-Highlighting to my search results.

In my custom display template, I have both 'HitHighlightedSummary' and the 'HitHighlightedProperties' properties in the ManagedPropertyMapping section.

I am displaying the document title in the search result which I want to highlight.

I have the title configured in the JSON Hit-Highlighting section in the Search Results web part configuration, but the title is still doesn't get highlighted even when the search results matches what gets typed in the search box.

[image]

Am I doing something incorrect here?

Please reply.

Thank you.
A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. To get the highlighting to work, the code:

```
var variableName = ctx.CurrentItem.csr_id;
```

needs to be changed to:

```
var variableName = ctx.CurrentItem.HitHighlightedProperties;
```

and then use the 'variableName' to get the value of the property, here in this case it is 'Title'

```
var titleHitHighlighted = Srch.U.getHighlightedProperty(variableName , ctx.CurrentItem, "Title");
```

and then in the body of the page, use the variable like so:

```
<div>
_#= titleHitHighlighted =#_
</div>
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add the highlighting of the title in your custom display template as below:

```
/* start: getting value of hit-highlighted property */

/* use this snippet to extract the value of a hit highlighted property */

/* get the current item id */

var csr_id = ctx.CurrentItem.csr_id;

/* get the hit-highlighted value */

var titleHitHighlighted = Srch.U.getHighlightedProperty(csr_id, ctx.CurrentItem, "Title");

/* get the original value in case nothing was returned in the previous */

if ($isEmptyString(titleHitHighlighted)) {titleHitHighlighted = $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);}

/* end: getting value of hit-highlighted property */
```

And to render the html, use it as below:

```
<!– custom HTML markup to render the title –>

<div class="highlightedTitle">

_#= titleHitHighlighted =#_

</div>

<!– end custom markup –>
```

Reference - [Applying Hit-Highlighting to any property in the Search Results WebPart in SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nadeemis/2012/10/16/applying-hit-highlighting-to-any-property-in-the-search-results-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried adding your code. The highlighting doesn't seem to work. The code 'ctx.CurrentItem.csr_id' simply returns an 'undefined' value. Is there something I need to check here? Thank you

Comment: I think what you have done is customize the result type. What you need to do is create a custom display template. 
http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

here, an example of item person template is displayed is show. You can create a copy of the item_commonitem_body and then customize it as per my code and then apply it to search results

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The reason why I am using the 'Result type for item' option is that I am displaying some crawled properties in my custom search results. Can't I achieve the Hit-Highlighting using the 'Result type for item' option ? Would I need to choose the 'Item Display Template' instead of the 'Result type for item' option?  Thank you